# Mapview in a separate fragment in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am writing an app that needs to display a `Map`. The screen consists of two parts - top and bottom. bottom part contains four buttons to mimic a toolbar at the bottom. The top part displays fragments as required by the button click. one such fragment contains `MapView`. I cannot include a static `MapFragment` because I need to replace the fragments. The problem is that while the mapview is correctly initialized(it shows a grid and two buttons + & -) no map is displayed. I am using the below code -

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.opaxlabs.text.MyMapFragment" >

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/myMap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this in the fragment class -

```
public class MyMapFragment extends Fragment {
    private MapView map;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    public MyMapFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        map=(MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.myMap);
        map.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mMap=map.getMap();
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(43.1, -87.9), 10);
        mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        return v;
    }

}
```

Edit: This is my manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.opaxlabs.text"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.opaxlabs.text.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.opaxlabs.text.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDWh4filEQQH6MSUU8N1ZbjomTxhu005WQ" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

</manifest>
```

Am I missing something?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Better to implement `MapFragment` instead of `MapView`.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html) simple tutorial to set up the Google map. Its very easy to understand and implement

Comment: I have gone through the tutorial for another project and it works great. But in this case I cannot use mapfragment statically. I need to replace the fragments on button clicks.

Comment: Look, it is always good to use MapFragment for this implementation and also for future changes and implementation.

Comment: is it possible to replace frameview with mapfragment, because I need to replace the fragments dynamically. I tried to replace using getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.top, new MapFragment()).addToBackStack("Map").commit(); But this did not work.

Comment: Please describe your requirements, and be specific for what you want to achieve exactly, so that i can help you

Comment: I have an activity that has four buttons at the bottom. each button loads a fragment in the activity. one of them is map. I have to switch these fragments on button clicks. creating an instance of mapfragments and replacing the framelayout does not work so I was forced to use mapview which is also not showing the map properly. It shows only a grid and 2 bottons + & -. I tried a separate activity with map fragment and it shows the map properly so it is not a case of wrong api key.

Comment: OK, First create 4 different fragments that you requires. After that include that all fragments in to the top container of your layout file. And then show/hide each fragment as according to button click. And extends base Activity as FragmentActivity. And set visibility true of default fragment that you have to show very first. Make sure that each fragment included into a separate layout(Linear/Relative) so that you can easily show/hide that layout programmatically on button click.

Answer (score 0):

To display a google map you need a google api key. Read this to get your key: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: Usually you have that behaviour (...it shows a grid and two buttons + & -) because the API Key is not correct. Please consider, if you're using the debug certificate, that it's different from machine to machine (in case the key has not been created on your pc). Also, it would be helpful to have your manifest to see if everything is fine. Thanks.